# RSpec test looped output

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to test the output of the following method:

```
def print_books
  @books.each do |book|
    puts "#{book.id}. #{book.name}"
  end
end
```

My RSpec code looks like :

```
before(:all) do 
 @library = Library.new
end

it "prints the correct names with ascendant ids" do 
  expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with("4. Harry Potter","8. Lord of the Rings")
  @library.print_books
end
```

The problem is only the first book is printed, as I think only the first output is taken into account.

Comment: how @library is initialized ?

Comment: I updated the description, the Library is initialized with a text file containing in each line Books as JSON Objects

Comment: Oh cool, yeah. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to test puts in rspec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709317/how-to-test-puts-in-rspec). The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21025146/2981429) looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `with(a, b)`, you're telling RSpec you expect the method to be called *once* with arguments `a, b`. For example, this will pass:

```
it 'prints' do
  expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with(1, 2)
  puts 1, 2
end
```

You're trying to do something different; you want `puts` to be called with `book_a`, and then *called again* with `book_b`. You can use [`ordered`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/message-order) to specify this to RSpec.

```
it 'prints each book' do
  expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with('1. Harry Potter').ordered
  expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with('8. Lord of the Rings').ordered
  @library.print_books
end
```

RSpec will now check that `puts` is called first with `"1. Harry Potter"`, then with `"8. Lord of the Rings"`. If one is missing, a third book is present, or the calls are made in the wrong order, the test will fail.